# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int when executed from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following SQL query string

```
sql = "SELECT TOP(1) [Date], BC_1MONTH, BC_2MONTH, BC_3MONTH, BC_6MONTH, BC_1YEAR, BC_2YEAR, BC_3YEAR, BC_5YEAR, BC_7YEAR, BC_10YEAR, BC_20YEAR, BC_30YEAR FROM Table_Curve WHERE Date = 2004-01-02"
```

That a C# program is trying to execute:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(credentials))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
....
```

I get the following exception:

> "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

When I execute this from SSMS it is fine:

```
SELECT[Date]
      ,[BC_1MONTH]
      ,[BC_2MONTH]
      ,[BC_3MONTH]
      ,[BC_6MONTH]
      ,[BC_1YEAR]
      ,[BC_2YEAR]
      ,[BC_3YEAR]
      ,[BC_5YEAR]
      ,[BC_7YEAR]
      ,[BC_10YEAR]
      ,[BC_20YEAR]
      ,[BC_30YEAR]
  FROM [IRs].[dbo].[Table_Curve]
  where date = '2012-02-16'
```

Comment: There's a difference between what you run in SQL Management Studio and whtat you run in C#. Look at the WHERE clause.

Comment: Your're right. Annoying.

Comment: It happens. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your date parameter with single quotes.

```
sql = "SELECT  TOP(1) [Date], BC_1MONTH, BC_2MONTH, BC_3MONTH, BC_6MONTH, BC_1YEAR, BC_2YEAR, BC_3YEAR, BC_5YEAR, BC_7YEAR, BC_10YEAR, BC_20YEAR, BC_30YEAR  FROM Table_Curve  WHERE Date = '2004-01-02'"
```

Comment: @Dale That edit makes the code not compile.

Comment: Ah yes that's the problem. Ugh! Thanks.